# Verificar checkbox criado dinamicamente

Tags: jquery, checkbox, dom

Boa tarde.

Preciso verificar se um checkbox criado dinamicamente (está dentro de um modal) está marcado. Como foi criado dinamicamente, pensei no seguinte código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', '#elemento', function () {
      if($(document).on("input[id='elemento']:checked")) {
         alert('Sim');
      } else {
         alert('Não');
      }
   });
});
```

O problema é que essa função retorna sempre verdadeiro. Não posso usar ***this.checked*** pq ela irá fazer referência ao document, e não ao checkbox. Não consigo entender o que está errado. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: dps da linha de codigo que vc cria esse check , vc pode colocar `$("input").each(function(){ if($(this).is(":checked") == true)console.log("checked")}`

Comment: Ocorre que estou abrindo o modal pelo data-target, sem escrever código jquery.

Comment: Vc quer verificar o checkbox sem escrever código?

Comment: Não. O código experimentado em jquery está na pergunta. O modal que é aberto direto pelo id definido na div referente ao modal, no próprio HTML.

Comment: Sim, mas isso irá fazer referência ao document, e não ao elemento. O ponto central é que o checkbox é criado dinamicamente quando o modal é mostrado. Consegui inserir a função no evento click do checkbox $(document).on('click', '#elemento', function (), então esta parte está ok. O problema está na linha if($(document).on("input[id='elemento']:checked")), que retorna sempre verdadeiro e eu não consigo entender o motivo. Sou iniciante em jquery.

Comment: O `$(this)` irá fazer referência ao `#elemento` , que foi informado no `.on("click")`.

Comment: Se tivesse só `$(document).on('click', function () {`, aí sim seria ao documento... mas vc colocou `#elemento` como referência.

Comment: ÐvÐ, funcionou. Fiz o que você sugeriu, ocorre que havia testado isso antes e não tinha conseguido. Devo ter esquecido algo da primeira vez. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Certo. Agradeço mais uma vez.

Comment: Como botei na resposta, o erro era pq o if estava verificando se o elemento existe e não se estava checado. Quando bota um elemento dentro do if, sem fazer nenhuma comparação, por ex.: `if( $('#elemento') ){` significa que vc quer saber se o elemento existe, já assim: `if( !$('#elemento') ){` (com "!" exclamação) significa que vc quer saber se o elemento não existe. Fico contente em ter ajudado. Se puder marcar ✓ na resposta para finalizar, seria bom. Abs!

Comment: Marquei! Não havia marcado antes pq ainda estou me familiarizando com o stackoverflow. Abs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o código `$(document).on("input[id='elemento']:checked")` não irá retornar o valor do `checkbox`, e sim se o elemento `#elemento` existe no `document`, e portanto o `if` retornará sempre verdadeiro.

Para verificar o `checkbox`, troque o `if` por:

```
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
```

Ficando assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', '#elemento', function () {
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         alert('Sim');
      } else {
         alert('Não');
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="elemento" checked="checked" />
```